# Call multiple functions from AJAX and return separate data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get two distinct results from AJAX calls. I pass in `_functionToRun` to the PHP file, which uses a switch statement to determine which function to run.

In the PHP file, I echo out two different arrays of words... `newQuestWords()` should only return some of the words. `parseHoveredText()` should return all vocab in the database.

Yet it seems when I echo out both, just all of the vocab is returned...

For example, in the JavaScript, `log(hoveredWords[i]);` should show all of the vocab available in the database, as returned from `` `parseHoveredText() `` function, but it doesn't show anything.

Why is that?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //initially append words to word bank   
    $.getJSON("php/Quests.php", { "_questNum" : questNum, "_functionToRun" : 1},
        function(returned_data) {
            wordsArray = returned_data;
            $.each(wordsArray, function(key, value) {   
                $(".wordBank_Words").append("<span class='bankword' data-display-word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + value + "</span><br/>");
            }
        );
    }); 

    //get all chinese/english words for hover over translation
    $.getJSON("php/Quests.php", {"_functionToRun" : 2},
        function(returned_data) {
            hoveredWords = returned_data;
            for (var i = 0; i < hoveredWords.length; i++) {
                log(hoveredWords[i]);
            }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    //if user's input is correct, increment task number, get next vocabulary
    $functionToRun = (isset($_GET['_functionToRun'])) ? $_GET['_functionToRun'] : 1;
    parseHoveredText();

    switch ($functionToRun) 
    {
        case 1:
            newQuestWords();
            break;
        case 2:
            parseHoveredText();
            break;
        default:
            echo "defaulted...";
    }


    function newQuestWords () {
        include 'DbConnect.php';
        $questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum'])) ? $_GET['_questNum'] : 1;

        $qry = 
         "SELECT t.*, v.* 
         FROM task t 
         INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
         INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
         WHERE vt.taskid = " . $questNumber;

        $sql = $mysqli->query($qry);

        $wordsArray = array();
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli);  
        echo  json_encode($wordsArray);

    }

    function parseHoveredText () {
        include 'DbConnect.php';

        $qry = 
         "SELECT v.*
         FROM vocab v";

        $sql = $mysqli->query($qry);

        $hoveredWords = array();
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            $hoveredWords[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli);  
        //return Chinese and English Words
        echo  json_encode($hoveredWords);

    }   
?>
```

Comment: Have you tested that parseHoveredText function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump return_data, it is json object not an array you can iterate. You can iterate through it this way

```
...
function(returned_data) {
    for (word in returned_data) {
        console.log(word);
    }
}
...
```

Or with $.each

```
...
$.each(returned_data, function(key, value) {   
    console.log(value);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But both the `for` and `each` loops do not output data

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log(returned_data);`?

Comment: Access the page php/Quests.php?_functionToRun=2 and see if something is outputed. If not, there is problem in PHP code, so take a look to error log.

Comment: like so? `http://localhost/Chinese%20Game%20Server/Game.php/php/Quests.php?_functionToRun=2`. This just gives me the plain HTML

Comment: It should give you $hoveredWords in JSON format. Something like `{'漢':'english word',...}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46654/discussion-between-growler-and-michal-brasna)